# How to lock the MainThread in C# Application?

Tags: c#

How to lock the MainThread in C# Application

Something like

```
lock (Thread.CurrentThread) // This will give the current running thread
{
// Bolck of Sync Codes
}
```

I do have some worker Threads also .. But i need to lock the MainThread and to execute 
some code ..

Can anyone help me on this ..

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Threads aren't usually locked, but objects

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to lock on the CurrentThread object ? for different threads, this value will be different and multiple threads can enter this block anyway.

If you're trying to avoid multiple threads from entering the block shown above, all threads should try to acquire a lock on an agreed-upon common object.
define a member like

```
private member object m_objectForLock;
```

and 
obtain a lock like this

```
lock(m_objectForLock)
{
  // Block of sync codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, and needs ellaboration.

But to share objects amongst several sperate threads, some kind of lock / sync mechanism has to be applied.

One way of accomplishing this is to use a lockobject in the following way:

```
    private object _objectLock;

    private void DoWork()
    {
        lock (_objectLock)
        {
            //Code to execute 
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, if you'd like to "hold" the execution of a thread, you could consider using System.Threading.EventWaitHandle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, but..

Blocking automatically happens in your thread if you don't explicitely call a method asynchronously. Blocking is no feature in this context but a consequence.

The use of `lock` in your sample is for explicit access to a variable in an asynchronous context.